# How to sort a 3d tensor by coordinates in last dimension (pytorch)

Tags: python, sorting, pytorch

I have a tensor with shape `[bn, k, 2]`. The last dimension are coordinates and I want each batch to be sorted independently depending on the y coordinate (`[:, :, 0]`). My approach looks something like this:

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(2, 5, 2)
indices = a[:, :, 0].sort()[1]
a_sorted = a[:, indices]

print(a)
print(a_sorted)
```

So far so good, but I now it sorts both batches according to both index lists, so I get 4 batches in total:

```
a
tensor([[[ 0.5160,  0.3257],
         [-1.2410, -0.8361],
         [ 1.3826, -1.1308],
         [ 0.0338,  0.1665],
         [-0.9375, -0.3081]],

        [[ 0.4140, -1.0962],
         [ 0.9847, -0.7231],
         [-0.0110,  0.6437],
         [-0.4914,  0.2473],
         [-0.0938, -0.0722]]])

a_sorted
tensor([[[[-1.2410, -0.8361],
          [-0.9375, -0.3081],
          [ 0.0338,  0.1665],
          [ 0.5160,  0.3257],
          [ 1.3826, -1.1308]],

         [[ 0.0338,  0.1665],
          [-0.9375, -0.3081],
          [ 1.3826, -1.1308],
          [ 0.5160,  0.3257],
          [-1.2410, -0.8361]]],


        [[[ 0.9847, -0.7231],
          [-0.0938, -0.0722],
          [-0.4914,  0.2473],
          [ 0.4140, -1.0962],
          [-0.0110,  0.6437]],

         [[-0.4914,  0.2473],
          [-0.0938, -0.0722],
          [-0.0110,  0.6437],
          [ 0.4140, -1.0962],
          [ 0.9847, -0.7231]]]])
```

As you can see, I want only the 1st and the 4th batch to be returned. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want: concatenation of `a[0, indices[0]]` and `a[1, indices[1]]`.

What you coded: concatenation of `a[0, indices]` and `a[1, indices]`.

The issue you are facing is because the indices returned by `sort` are shaped like the first dimensions, but the *values* are only indices into the second dimension. When you go to use these, you want to match `indices[0]` on `a[0]`, but pytorch doesn't do this implicitly (because fancy indexing is very powerful, and needs this syntax for it's power). So, all you have to do is give a parallel list of indices for the first dimension.

i.e. You want to use something like: `a[[[0], [1]], indices]`.

To generalise this a bit more, you may use something like:

```py
n = a.shape[0]
first_indices = torch.arange(n)[:, None]
a[first_indices, indices]
```

This is a little tricksy, so here's an example:

```py
>>> a = torch.randn(2,4,2)
>>> a
tensor([[[-0.2050, -0.1651],
         [ 0.5688,  1.0082],
         [-1.5964, -0.9236],
         [ 0.3093, -0.2445]],

        [[ 1.0586,  1.0048],
         [ 0.0893,  2.4522],
         [ 2.1433, -1.2428],
         [ 0.1591,  2.4945]]])
>>> indices = a[:, :, 0].sort()[1]
>>> indices
tensor([[2, 0, 3, 1],
        [1, 3, 0, 2]])
>>> a[:, indices]
tensor([[[[-1.5964, -0.9236],
          [-0.2050, -0.1651],
          [ 0.3093, -0.2445],
          [ 0.5688,  1.0082]],

         [[ 0.5688,  1.0082],
          [ 0.3093, -0.2445],
          [-0.2050, -0.1651],
          [-1.5964, -0.9236]]],


        [[[ 2.1433, -1.2428],
          [ 1.0586,  1.0048],
          [ 0.1591,  2.4945],
          [ 0.0893,  2.4522]],

         [[ 0.0893,  2.4522],
          [ 0.1591,  2.4945],
          [ 1.0586,  1.0048],
          [ 2.1433, -1.2428]]]])
>>> a[0, indices]
tensor([[[-1.5964, -0.9236],
         [-0.2050, -0.1651],
         [ 0.3093, -0.2445],
         [ 0.5688,  1.0082]],

        [[ 0.5688,  1.0082],
         [ 0.3093, -0.2445],
         [-0.2050, -0.1651],
         [-1.5964, -0.9236]]])
>>> a[1, indices]
tensor([[[ 2.1433, -1.2428],
         [ 1.0586,  1.0048],
         [ 0.1591,  2.4945],
         [ 0.0893,  2.4522]],

        [[ 0.0893,  2.4522],
         [ 0.1591,  2.4945],
         [ 1.0586,  1.0048],
         [ 2.1433, -1.2428]]])
>>> a[0, indices[0]]
tensor([[-1.5964, -0.9236],
        [-0.2050, -0.1651],
        [ 0.3093, -0.2445],
        [ 0.5688,  1.0082]])
>>> a[1, indices[1]]
tensor([[ 0.0893,  2.4522],
        [ 0.1591,  2.4945],
        [ 1.0586,  1.0048],
        [ 2.1433, -1.2428]])
>>> a[[[0], [1]], indices]
tensor([[[-1.5964, -0.9236],
         [-0.2050, -0.1651],
         [ 0.3093, -0.2445],
         [ 0.5688,  1.0082]],

        [[ 0.0893,  2.4522],
         [ 0.1591,  2.4945],
         [ 1.0586,  1.0048],
         [ 2.1433, -1.2428]]])
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot, I learned much from your post. I already assumed that something like that should be the solution, but I didn't know how to implement it. Have a good day!